# Won't detect Mac OS X when I try to install

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

When I try to install, it will ask me to erase all data or something else. It says no OS installed either. I looked it up and it's supposed to say install alongside Mac OS X. How can I fix this and make it show up?

Comment: please refer [install-elementary-os-in-dual-boot-with-something-else-option](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/install-elementary-os-in-dual-boot-with-something-else-option)